# How can I shuffle a range of numbers and then split it into subarrays of a certain length?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a range `1:N`, I want to shuffle the range into a random order and then split the resulting shuffled array into subarrays that are at most `128` elements long. How can I do this?

This question is based by one that appeared on the JuliaLang slack channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `shuffle` from the `Random` standard library can be used to shuffle a container into random order:

```
julia> using Random: shuffle

julia> shuffle(1:10)
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  9
  3
  2
 10
  1
  8
  7
  5
  4
```

The function `Iterators.partition` from Julia's `Base` can be used to iterate over an iterable in chunks of a fixed length:

```
julia> using Base.Iterators: partition

julia> partition(1:20, 7)
Base.Iterators.PartitionIterator{UnitRange{Int64}}(1:20, 7)
```

However, `partition` returns a lazy iterator by default so if we want to materialize the actual result, we'll need to `collect` it:

```
julia> collect(partition(1:20, 7))
3-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 1:7
 8:14
 15:20
```

Putting this all together, we have

```
julia> using Random: shuffle

julia> using Base.Iterators: partition

julia> shuffle_partition(N; chunk_size=128) = (collect ∘ partition)(shuffle(1:N), chunk_size)
shuffle_partition (generic function with 1 method)

julia> shuffle_partition(503)
4-element Array{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true},1}:
 [313, 51, 117, 373, 381, 340, 342, 415, 423, 453  …  201, 178, 167, 242, 2, 76, 146, 439, 363, 448]
 [115, 121, 306, 440, 295, 181, 30, 280, 388, 227  …  362, 39, 317, 171, 55, 214, 261, 251, 96, 9]
 [486, 248, 161, 319, 325, 176, 80, 369, 434, 209  …  442, 350, 273, 419, 130, 305, 192, 482, 265, 234]
 [460, 31, 400, 466, 220, 447, 119, 446, 198, 141  …  226, 438, 74, 152, 203, 303, 378, 231, 458, 194]

julia> length.(ans)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 128
 128
 128
 119
```

---

This answer is based on the answer found on Slack.

Comment: There is a specific function just to create the permutation, `randperm(n) `

Answer (score 2):

using Iterators: 
I think the most simple is using randperm (if the values are between 1 and N), so

```
using Base.Iterators: partition
using Random: randperm

N = 513
k = 128

collect(partition(randperm(N), k))
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
parts = view.(Ref(shuffle(1:N)),(i:min(i+k-1, N) for i in 1:k:N))
```

This assumes `N` is the number of elements and parition size is `k`. The obtained result is a list of views (hence shuffled 1:N is stored only once in the memory). Note how `Ref` is used to avoid vectorization over the shuffled list.

Sample test code:

```
julia> using Random

julia> N, k = 20, 4;

julia> parts = view.(Ref(shuffle(1:N)),(i:min(i+k-1, N) for i in 1:k:N))
5-element Array{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true},1}:
 [18, 15, 1, 6]
 [10, 20, 4, 14]
 [17, 9, 19, 16]
 [5, 8, 12, 3]
 [11, 13, 2, 7]
```