# Random iteration in Julia Programming

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

When you want to iterate sequentially over a list of numbers from 1 to N in Julia you will write:

```
for i in 1:N
   # do something with i
end
```

But what if you want to iterate over the list of numbers from the range (1...N) randomly? There is a need in every iteration to randomly choose the number that wasn't chosen in any previous iteration and there is a need to iterate over all of the numbers from the range (1...N).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557139/how-can-i-shuffle-a-range-of-numbers-and-then-split-it-into-subarrays-of-a-certa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I shuffle a range of numbers and then split it into subarrays of a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557139/how-can-i-shuffle-a-range-of-numbers-and-then-split-it-into-subarrays-of-a-certa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using Random

for i in shuffle(1:N)
   # do something with i
end
```